# How does our brain sense the passage of time?

Tags: neuroscience, time

How does our brain sense the **passage of time**? What is the mechanism? I am not asking here about memory. I have searched about it on the internet. 
https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/your-brain-has-two-clocks/
I found this- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4830363/ 
So does this mean (so as to explain it in a simple way to understand it easily), that our brain somehow create intrinsic repetitive processes analogous to clocks & in turn process information from it so as to *sense* time? Is that information fed to the center(s) responsible for consciousness to further process information?

Comment: I think your question is very interesting. But it’s a difficult question. I’m interested in this issue too and tried to find more recent literature about it but couldn’t find any that is later than the second reference you’ve given. As the reference puts it, the neural mechanisms of time perception are not yet fully understood. It seems to me that it is so. That’s probably why your questions haven’t been answered yet. However, for me, the answers to your last two questions are yes. Hope someone here will finally give a better comment or even will give you a more definite answer.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you clarify the *time frame*: the mechanisms for passage of seconds versus hours versus years are likely distinct.